# A question about ideal of a polynomial and its vanishing set

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to show the following, but not sure how to proceed:

> Let $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Suppose that $g,h \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ s.t. for all $(a,b) \in V(f)$ we have $g(a,b)=h(a,b)$. Then the polynomial $g(x,y)-h(x,y) \in \langle x^2 + y^2 -1 \rangle$.

Now I know that on the set of points in $V(f)$ $g(a,b)-h(a,b) =f(a,b)$. Then intuitively I would think that $g(x,y)-h(x,y) = f(x,y)$ but this doesn't need to be the case I guess right? Otherwise the problem would be trivial.

Comment: Do you mean $<g(x,y)-h(x,y)>=<f(x,y)>$?

Comment: @MathIsNice1729 no sorry I meant $g(x,y)-h(x,y) \in <x^2 + y^2 -1>$. It was a typo

Comment: Do you know the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop yes.

Comment: Ah well it looks like you already got an answer using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, $g(x,y)-h(x,y)=0$ in $V(f)$.

Then, $g-h \in I(V(f))=\sqrt{\langle f \rangle}=\langle f\rangle$, since $f$ is prime in $\Bbb C[x,y]$.

Comment: The first equality follows because $I(V(f)) = I(V(\langle f \rangle))$ right?

Comment: @mathripper Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Set $F(x,y)=g(x,y)-h(x,y)$. From the fact that $F(a,b)=0$, for every $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+b^2=1$ you'd like to prove that $F(x,y)=G(x,y)(x^2+y^2-1)$ for some polynomial $G$.

Let's consider $F$ as an element of $\mathbb{C}(x)[y]$, where we can perform the division
$$
F(x,y)=Q(x,y)(y^2+x^2-1)+U(x)y+V(x)
$$
where $Q\in\mathbb{C}(x)[y]$ and $U,V\in\mathbb{C}(x)$. If $(a,b)\in V(f)$, then
$$
0=U(a)b+V(a)
$$
Writing $U=U_0/W,V=V_0/W$, where $U_0,V_0,W\in\mathbb{C}[x]$, we obtain $U_0(a)b+V_0(a)=0$. In particular $U_0(a)^2b^2=V_0(a)^2$, which yields
$$
U_0(a)^2(1-a^2)-V_0(a)^2=0
$$
Thus the polynomial $U_0(x)^2(1-x^2)-V_0(x)^2$ has infinitely many roots and therefore is the zero polynomial. This is a contradiction, because $1+x$ divides $U_0(x)^2(1-x^2)$ an odd number of times, but $V_0(x)^2$ an even number of times.